# Python subtract first element from each respective row of matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I want to subtract the first value of a row from the rest of the elements of that row, so for

```
import numpy as np

z = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,9]])

for n in range(0,3):
    znew = z[n,:]-z[n,0]
```

`znew` should be `np.array([[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,2]])`. How can I do this? It kind of seems trivial.

Comment: Last row should be `[0, 1, 2, 2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by taking advantage of broadcasting:

```
>>> z - z[:,0][:, None] # or z - z[:,0][:, np.newaxis]
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 2]])
```